# is the null character included in the return value of the function strtok?

Tags: c, string

For the string returned by `strtok`, does it have a `\0` at the end?
Or does it not, like the `strncpy` function?

I would check by copying the return value of `strtok` to another string array with `strcpy`, but then I wouldn't know if the appended `\0` was the effect of `strtok` or `strcpy` (since `strcpy` does add `\0`).

edit: sorry, I can't "copy the return value to of `strtok` to another string array with `strcpy`".

Comment: Remember to check the documentation first - especially in cases where it is relatively easy to find (i.e. the function name is known).

Answer (score 11):

From [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/)

> This end of the token is automatically replaced by a null-character,
>   and the beginning of the token is returned by the function.

Comment: I know the end of the token IN THE ORIGINAL STRING is replaced by the null character. but that's different from what's being returned. I want to know if the RETURNED VALUE has a null character at the end? or is it implied that the returned value doesn't have a null character at the end, since it's the "beginning" of the token? I'm unclear about what is meant by "beginning" and "end". does the "beginning" include the replaced null character or not?

Comment: @user81055 strtok is old-school C. There is only the original-and-maybe-modified data.

Comment: Well that's why debug exist. It **is** put null-character at the end of the string.

Comment: @user81055 I think you need to work on understanding pointers first, then you will understand that there is no such thing as a "string", just an array of 8-bit integers, the end of which is indicated by 0. `strtok` returns a pointer to where you should look within the array you passed it, setting a 0 in the appropriate place to mark the end of the relevant portion.

Answer (score 8):

From C99 7.24.5.8

> The strtok function then searches from there for a character that is contained in the
>   current separator string. If no such character is found, the current token extends to the
>   end of the string pointed to by s1, and subsequent searches for a token will return a null
>   pointer. If such a character is found, **it is overwritten by a null character**, which
>   terminates the current token. The strtok function saves a pointer to the following
>   character, from which the next search for a token will start.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, each token returned by `strtok` has `'\0'` at the end. It is not just "included" it is actually forcefully written into your input string. `strtok` returns pointers that point into your original input string and it also destroys your input string in the process by writing those `'\0'` into it. It is a very poorly designed function, which is best avoided.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a null terminator. It is at the delimiter last found. This is the reason that the first argument to strtok is not a `const char *`: it modifies the buffer you gave it, meaning it cannot be const.

```
char buffer[0x20];
char *token;

sprintf(buffer, "Hello, world!");
printf("Address of BUFFER before strtok: %p\n", (void *)buffer);
token = strtok(buffer, ", !");
printf("Address of TOKEN after strtok: %p\n", (void *)token);
printf("Value of BUFFER: %s\n", buffer);
printf("Value of TOKEN: %s\n", token);
```

Run that, and you will understand that the first string passed is modified by strtok to change whatever delimiter after the first character was found first to a null terminator, meaning if you used ",,,Hello,,, world!", it would return "Hello\0,, world!".

After the first call to strtok, you can parse more tokens by passing NULL as the first argument to strtok. It will find the next non-delimiter token on its own. You can continue to do this until strtok returns NULL, in which case there are no more matches.

Answer (score -1):

Yes,it does.From [cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/)

> To determine the beginning and the end of a token, the function first
>   scans from the starting location for the first character not contained
>   in delimiters (which becomes the beginning of the token). And then
>   scans starting from this beginning of the token for the first
>   character contained in delimiters, which becomes the end of the token.
>   The scan also stops if the terminating null character is found.

I did like this to check whether the strtok appends  `'\0'` or not :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
  char str[]="here !is the! damn code";
  setbuf(stdout,NULL);
  char s[]="!";
  char *token;
  token=strtok(str,s);//first call: the function here expects str as argument and first scans from the starting location for the first character not contained in delimiters.
  while(token!=NULL)
    {

      if(*token!='\0')
        {
         printf("the end of the token is replaced by a null character");// printed for each token which means that the delimiter was replaced by null character,and lastly at the end of the string.
         printf("and the token is : %s\n",token);// tokens are printed
        }
      token=strtok(NULL,s);// the function expects a null pointer(NULL) and uses the position right after the end of last token as the new starting location for scanning in the subsequent calls.
    }      
  return 0;
}
```

The number of delimiters are put to divide the `str` in *tokens* and end of the token is replaced by the null character. Therefore the statements are printed for each token meaning if token would not have ended with a null character the statements would have printed only once i.e at the end.

Comment: "*... //here token is checked whether  it contains \0 or not ...*": Your comment is misleading: `while(token!='\0')` checks whether `token` is equal `0`, will say does point to anything. which has nothing to do with the OP's question referring the result of `strtok()` being `'\0'`-terminated. Btw: It should better read: `while(token!=NULL)`, as `token` is a pointer.

Comment: @alk Ok, thanks for the clarification. But the `strtok` returns to `token` and that must contain the '\0' .mustn't it?

Comment: As **already pointed out by various other answers to this question**: `strtok()` either returns `NULL` or a reference to some element from the character array passed in to the initial call to `strtok()`. This inital string is patched with `'\0'` where a delimiting character (as given by the second parameter passed to the initial call to strtok()`) was found.

Comment: I'd better change this answer significantly or simply delete it, as it does not refer to the OP's question at all.

Comment: Yes, pointers are dereferenced by the `*`-operator. And again yes, as `token` is declared as `char *` you could compare `*token` against a `'\0'`. But you know this, don't you?

Comment: "*... if(*token=='\0');// the end of the token is automatically replaced by the null character and this checks whether it contains or not ...*" this is wrong, as the first character of what token` is pointing to is checked, and this most propably **never** is `'\0'`.

Comment: "*... if it does then "it does" is printed ...*" this is also wrong, as `"it does"` is printed always.